# List vs dictionary to store zeroes in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am solving a problem in which I need a list of zeroes and after that I have to update some values in the list . Now I have two options in my mind how can I do this first is to simply make a list of zeroes and then update the values or I create a dictionary and then I update values .

**List method :**

```
l=[0]*n
```

**Dictionary method :**

```
d={}
for i in range(n):
    d[i]=0
```

Now to complexity to build dictionary is `O(n)` and  then updating a key is `O(1)` . But I don't know how python builds the list of zeroes using above method .

Let's assume n is a large number which one the above method will be better for this task ? and how is the list method implemented in python ? . Also why is the above list method faster than list comprehension method for creating list of zeroes ?

Comment: I suggest you do some experiments, print the running time and see the autual difference.

Comment: The dictionary initialization is better as: `dict.fromkeys(range(n), 0)`.

Comment: `l=[0]*n` simply does `l = list.__mul__([0], n)` but uses a language construct. Sequence types usually implement `__mul__` used for repeating them.

Answer (score 2):

The access and update once you have pre-allocated your sequence will be roughly the same.

Pick a data-structure that makes sense for your application. In this case I suggest a list because it more naturally fits "sequence indexed by integers"

The reason [0]*n is fast is that it can make a list of the correct size in one go, rather than constantly expanding the list as more elements are added.

Answer (score 1):

After running a test using `timeit`:

```
import timeit
timeit.repeat("[0]*1000", number=1000000)
#[4.489016328923801, 4.459866205812087, 4.477892545204176]

timeit.repeat("""d={}
for i in range(1000):
d[i]=0""", number=1000000)
#[77.77789647192793, 77.88324065372811, 77.7300221235187]

timeit.repeat("""x={};x.fromkeys(range(1000),0)""", number=1000000)
#[53.62738158027423, 53.87422525293914, 53.50821399216625]
```

As you can see there is HUGE difference between these two methods and third one is better but not as lists! The reason is creating a `list` with size specified is way too faster than creating a `dictionary` with expanding it over iteration.

Comment: Try: python -mtimeit -s 'x={}' 'x.fromkeys(range(1000),0)'

Answer (score 1):

I think in this situation you should just use list, unless you want to access some data without using index.

Python list is an array. It initializes with a specific size, when it needs to store more items than its size can hold, it just copies everything to a new array, and the copying is O(k), where k is the then size of the list. this process can happen a lot of times until the list get to size bigger than or equal to n. However, [0]*n will just create the array with the right size (which is n), so it's faster than updating the list to the right size from the beginning.

For creation by list comprehension, if you mean something like `[0 for i in range(n)]`, I think it suffers from updating the list size and so it is slower.

Python dictionary is an implementation of Hash Table, and it use a hash function to calculate the hash value for the key when you insert a new key-value pair. The execution of hash function itself is comparatively expensive, and dictionary also deals with other situations like collision, which makes it even slower. Thus, creation 0s by dictionary should be the slowest, in theory.

Answer (score 1):

`collections.defaultdict` may be a better solution if you expect that a lot of elements will not change during your updates keeping initial value (and if you don't rely on `KeyError`s somehow). Just

```
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(int)

assert d[42] == 0
d[43] = 1
# ...
```

Another thing to consider is `array.array`. You can use it if you want to store only elements (counts) of one type. It should be a little faster and memory efficient than lists:

```
import array
l = array.array('L', [0]) * n
# use as list
```